# I am trying to find a specific digit in a number using recursion in python

Tags: python

```
def checkLuckyDigit(num):
    if num == 0:
        return False
    elif (num%10) == 8:
        return True
    else:
        checkLuckyDigit(num//10)

num = int(input("Enter a number = "))

if(checkLuckyDigit(num)):
    print("There is a lucky digit")
else:
    print("There is no lucky digit")
```

In the above code i need to find out whether the user entered number has **8** in it or not , when i enter **4348** it displays **There is a lucky digit** but when i enter **3438434** it displays **There is no lucky digit** and the function returns **None**.

I recently moved from C++ to python so i am really confused what my mistake is.

Comment: that wouldn't work in C++ either

Comment: You can also do `'8' in str(num)` btw

Comment: There is a much easier way of checking if a number has a digit, `"8" in str(num)`  if you don't need to use recursion.

Comment: @dawg the professor restricted strings but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a Python function reaches the end with no `return`, it implicitly returns `None`, which is what happens when you hit your recursive call. You just need to change the last line to `return checkLuckyDigit(num//10)`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't handle the unwinding condition
Do it like this

```
def checkLuckyDigit(num):
    if num > 0:
        if num % 10 == 8:
            return True
        if checkLuckyDigit(num//10): #This checks the unwinding condition
                return True
    else:
        return False

num = int(input("Enter a number ="))


if checkLuckyDigit(num):
    print("There is a lucky digit")
else:
    print("There is no lucky digit")
```